# SQL query with UNION in Doctrine Symfony

Tags: sql, doctrine, pagination, symfony-1.4

I have a question about the translation of a SQL query in Doctrine Symfony. I would like to do a thing like that :

```
SELECT m.*
FROM member m
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id_member
  FROM friend
  WHERE id_friend=99
  UNION
  SELECT id_friend
  FROM friend
  WHERE id_member=99
) a ON m.id=a.id_member 
WHERE m.visible=1
```

In this example, i search all friends of the user 99.

**My tables :**

> **Member:** (id, name, visible)
>   **Friend:** (id, id_member,
>   id_friend, active)

Precision : I would like to use the Symfony pager.

A solution ? Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UNION is not supported within DQL, but you can issue your query using RAW SQL ->

```
$q = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
$result = $q->execute(" -- RAW SQL HERE -- ");
```

Answer (score 3):

Other alternative to @ManseUK is:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$statement = $connection->prepare("-- RAW SQL HERE --");
$statement->execute();

return $statement->fetchAll();
```