# UNION in createQuery with symfony2

Tags: sql, symfony, union, createquery

I'm trying

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT id, name, beginDate, endDate FROM SmartguideEntityBundle:Promotion1 UNION SELECT id, name, beginDate, endDate FROM SmartguideEntityBundle:Promotion2'
        );
```

But result is

```
Error: Expected end of string, got 'SELECT'
```

How can I resolve it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony createquery with union](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22453104/symfony-createquery-with-union)

Answer (score 1):

Try to define an **alias**, as in

```
SELECT p1.id, 
p1.name, 
p1.beginDate, 
p1.endDate 
FROM SmartguideEntityBundle:Promotion1 p1 
UNION 
SELECT p2.id, 
p2.name, 
p2.beginDate, 
p2.endDate 
FROM SmartguideEntityBundle:Promotion2 p2
```

**EDIT**: If you take a look at this link, ti shows how to execute the query using **RAW SQL** ([SQL query with UNION in Doctrine Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981549/sql-query-with-union-in-doctrine-symfony))

Comment: I got message "Error: Expected end of string, got 'UNION' when using alias

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $em->getConnection();
$result = $stmt->executeQuery(-your sql-)->fetchAll();
```