# Symfony createquery with union

Tags: sql, symfony

I need to execute the next query with symfony :

```
$qb = $this->_em;
$query = $qb->createQuery(
    'SELECT f1.friend1
    FROM AppBundle:Friend f1
    WHERE f1.friend2 = ?1
    UNION
    SELECT f2.friend2
    FROM AppBundle:Friend f2
    WHERE f2.friend1 = ?2
    '
)->setParameters(array(1 => $user_id, 2 => $user_id));
```

When i execute this `$query`, i have this error : `Expected end of string, got 'UNION'`.

How can i do ?

Edit for my new code :

```
    $rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult('Project\MyBundle\Entity\Friend', 'f');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('f', 'friend1', 'friend1');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('f', 'friend2', 'friend2');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('f', 'id', 'id');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('f', 'state', 'state');
    $sql = "SELECT f1.friend1 AS friend
        FROM friend f1
        WHERE f1.friend2 = ?
        UNION
        SELECT f2.friend2  AS friend
        FROM friend f2
        WHERE f2.friend1 = ?";
    $result = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)
    ->setParameter(1, $user_id)
    ->setParameter(2, $user_id)
    ->getResult();

    return $result;
```

This is my new query. I have test this query directly on phpmyadmin, and i have a return. But with this code, i have empty in $result

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` is not supported in doctrine instead you can use [**Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping;**](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) this will map your resultset to the entity which you defined to use by the native query like `$rsm->addEntityResult('Namespace\yourBundle\Entity\Friend', 'f');`

```
$rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult('Namespace\yourBundle\Entity\Friend', 'f');
$rsm->addFieldResult('f', 'friend', 'friend1');    
$sql = "SELECT f1.friend1 AS friend
    FROM friend_table f1
    WHERE f1.friend2 = ?
    UNION
    SELECT f2.friend2  AS friend
    FROM friend_table f2
    WHERE f2.friend1 = ?";
$result = $DM->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)
->setParameter(1, $user_id)
->setParameter(2,$user_id)
->getResult();
```

**Edit from comments**

---

Not advisable solution due to lack of information why using union but the answer for question in comments below you can do so to map fields,but remember this will give you the duplicates

```
$rsm = new \Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult('Project\MyBundle\Entity\Friend', 'f');
$rsm->addFieldResult('f', 'friend1', 'friend1');
$rsm->addFieldResult('f', 'friend2', 'friend2');
$rsm->addFieldResult('f', 'id', 'id');
$rsm->addFieldResult('f', 'state', 'state');
$sql = "SELECT f1.id,f1.friend1 AS friend,f1.friend1,f1.friend2 ,f1.state
    FROM friend f1
    WHERE f1.friend2 = ?
    UNION
    SELECT f2.id,f2.friend2  AS friend,f2.friend1,f2.friend2 ,f2.state
    FROM friend f2
    WHERE f2.friend1 = ?";
$result = $this->_em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm)
->setParameter(1, $user_id)
->setParameter(2, $user_id)
->getResult();
```

**Edit 2** *i just want an array with one field "friend", with friend1 in one case, and friend2 in another*

---

For the above you asked you can run two queries using your entity

```
$DM = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$result1=$DM->getRepository('Namespace\yourBundle\Entity\Friend')
->findBy(array('friend2'=>$user_id));
$result2=$DM->getRepository('Namespace\yourBundle\Entity\Friend')
->findBy(array('friend1'=>$user_id));
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\tw_symfony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 2487... do you know why ?

Comment: The piece of code you have shown there is no id variable is used can you post the full error details

Comment: if i change f1.friend1 and f2.friend2 by *, it's ok... Any ideas ?

Comment: @ClémentAndraud no its not ok you need to provide mapping for the fields as i have shown you the example to map `friend` on `friend1`

Comment: yeah, but i need to map friend on friend1 and friend2.. but it doesn't work

Comment: If you want to map all fields then whats is purpose for using union ,your are using `friend1` and `friend2` in select then whats the purpose of union ?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, but it's not want i want^^ You are right, i don't want duplicate (sorry), i just want an array with one field "friend", with friend1 in one case, and friend2 in another... Do you understand ? This query is just for retrieve the friend of a user. But this user can be in friend1 or friend2.