# Best approach to retrieve entity field form from database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have that Entity TwitterPost.php

```
<?php

namespace FEB\TwitterBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Twitterpost
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FEB\TwitterBundle\Entity\TwitterpostRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Twitterpost
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="titulo", type="string", length=50)
     * @Assert\NotNull(message="Debe escribir un titulo")
     */
    private $titulo;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tweet", type="string", length=145)
     * @Assert\NotNull(message="Debe escribir un tweet")
     */
    private $tweet;


    /**
     * Many-To-Many, Unidirectional
     *
     * @var ArrayCollection $tags
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\FEB\TagsBundle\Entity\Tag")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="twitterpost_tags",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="twitterpost_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $tags;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $photo;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="idpost", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $idpost;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="autor", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $autor;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;   


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCreated(new \DateTime());
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set titulo
     *
     * @param string $titulo
     * @return Twitterpost
     */
    public function setTitulo($titulo)
    {
        $this->titulo = $titulo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get titulo
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTitulo()
    {
        return $this->titulo;
    }

    /**
     * Set tweet
     *
     * @param string $tweet
     * @return Twitterpost
     */
    public function setTweet($tweet)
    {
        $this->tweet = $tweet;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tweet
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTweet()
    {
        return $this->tweet;
    }

    /**
     * Set tags
     *
     * @param string $tags
     * @return Twitterpost
     */
    public function setTags($tags)
    {
        $this->tags = $tags;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tags
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

    /**
     * Set photo
     *
     * @param string $photo
     * @return Twitterpost
     */
    public function setPhoto($photo)
    {
        $this->photo = $photo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get photo
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhoto()
    {
        return $this->photo;
    }

     /**
     * Set idpost
     *
     * @param string $idpost
     * @return Twitterpost
     */
    public function setIdPost($idpost)
    {
        $this->idpost = $idpost;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get idpost
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getIdPost()
    {
        return $this->idpost;
    }

   /**
     * Set autor
     *
     * @param string $autor
     * @return Twitterpost
     */
    public function setAutor($autor)
    {
        $this->autor = $autor;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get autor
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAutor()
    {
        return $this->autor;
    }   

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Tag
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }   
}
```

And this one

```
/**
 * Tag
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="FEB\TagsBundle\Entity\TagRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="tag", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $tag;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="autor", type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $autor;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setCreated(new \DateTime());
    }   


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set tag
     *
     * @param string $tag
     * @return Tag
     */
    public function setTag($tag)
    {
        $this->tag = $tag;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get tag
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTag()
    {
        return $this->tag;
    }

    /**
     * Set autor
     *
     * @param string $autor
     * @return Tag
     */
    public function setAutor($autor)
    {
        $this->autor = $autor;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get autor
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAutor()
    {
        return $this->autor;
    }

    /**
     * Set created
     *
     * @param \DateTime $created
     * @return Tag
     */
    public function setCreated($created)
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get created
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }
}
```

It's a Manytomany relationship between TwitterPost and Tags. And in my form has a select field which is a Entity class Tag.

```
<?php
namespace FEB\TwitterBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
class TwitterpostType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('titulo')
                ->add('tweet', 'textarea')
                ->add('photo', 'file', array('required' => false))              
                ->add('tags', 'entity', array(
                                                'class' =>    'FEBTagsBundle:tag',
                                                'property' => 'tag',
                                                'empty_value' => 'Selecciona tags',
                                                'multiple' => true));               
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'twitter_form';
    }
}
```

When I submit the data form, in the "twitterpost" table the data is saved correctly and in the aux table "twitterpost_tags" too.

For example:

```
twitterpost_id tag_id
1-----------1
1-----------2
2-----------1
2-----------3
The tag table:
id---------tag
1----------tagA
2----------tagB
3----------tagC
```

When I want show all data of Twitterpost, what is the best approached to show the tag name and not the tag id?

Than you in advanced.

Comment: I wonder if there is any way to insert in database this:
`twitterpost_id tag_id
1-----------tagA

1-----------tagB
2-----------tagA
2-----------tagC`
Instead of this:
`twitterpost_id tag_id
1-----------1
1-----------2
2-----------1
2-----------3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get you right. To show All **tags** in the twitterpost form you are already doing the right thing:

```
    ->add('tags', 'entity', array(
          'class' =>    'FEBTagsBundle:tag',
          'property' => 'tag',
          'empty_value' => 'Selecciona tags',
          'multiple' => true
));
```

This will create a multiple select box where you can select from all the tags. From [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html):

> **property**
>
> *type: string*
>
> This is the property that should be used for displaying the entities as text in the HTML element. If left blank, the entity object will be cast into a string and so must have a __toString() method.

If you don't want a *multi-select* but *checkboxes* or *radiobuttons* instead, checkout [this part of the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#forms-reference-choice-tags).

---

In case you are asking on how to output the data when not inside the `TwitterpostType`, you can just treat them as objects in a **Controller**:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TwitterBundle:Twitterpost');
$post = $repository->findOne($id);

// to get all _tags_ of a post just call the getter:
$tags = $post->getTags();
```

The same goes for **twig templates**:

```
{# imagine you have all posts in a variable called 'posts' #}
{% for post in posts %}
     <h1>{{ post.titulo }}</h1>
     <div class="tags">
         {% for tag in posts.tags %}
         {{ tag.tag }}
         {% endfor %}
     </div>
{% endfor %}
```

---

Edit:

For a native SQL / DQL query you need [a custom repository class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes). There you can store your own queries:

```
class TwitterpostRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllOrderedByName()
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT p FROM TwitterBundle:Twitterpost p ORDER BY p.name ASC'
            )
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this in the controller:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('TwitterBundle:Twitterpost');
$post = $repository->findAllOrderedByName();
```

Comment: First of all, thankyou for your response.
Yes, I meant how to ouput the data and It works perfectly. But I have a question. This approach is good when I want to output the Type data, ok, what if I wanted to make a NativeSql like a UNION instead findOne()? In this case I could not use this method, no?

Comment: Hi again!!! I have this:
  `return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT t.id FROM TwitterBundle:Twitterpost t UNION SELECT f.id FROM FacebookBundle:Facebookpost f'
            )
            ->getResult();`

And I got this error:

[Syntax Error] line 0, col 48: Error: Expected end of string, got 'UNION'

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155288/how-to-write-union-in-doctrine-2-0) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981549/sql-query-with-union-in-doctrine-symfony). If they don't solve your problem, create a new question please.