# mysql sum with named column

Tags: php, mysql

I have table where I have two columns `briefeng` and `briefbng`, I need the count of total null and not null values in a proper way:

Here is my sql code:

```
SELECT
Sum(If(brief_english Is Null, 1, 0)) AS briefeng,
Sum(If(brief_english Is NOT Null, 1, 0)) AS briefengnotnull,

Sum(If(brief_bangla Is Null, 1, 0)) AS briefbng
FROM synopsis;
```

but it returns a result like this way:

```
+----------+-----------------+----------+
| briefeng | briefengnotnull | briefbng |
+----------+-----------------+----------+
|      946 |             896 |      841 |
+----------+-----------------+----------+
```

But I need the result in this ways

```
 +----------+--------------+
 | status | total          |
 +----------+--------------+
 | briefeng |         946  |
 +----------+--------------+
 | briefengnotnull |  896  |
 +----------+--------------+
 | briefengnotnull |  841  |
 +----------+--------------+
```

How can I do that? I couldn't find a easy and efficient way.

Comment: Use 'union' or 'union all'

Answer (score 0):

Use union or union all like this :

```
SELECT
'briefeng' as status,
Sum(If(brief_english Is Null, 1, 0)) AS total
FROM synopsis
UNION ALL
SELECT
'briefengnotnull' as status,
Sum(If(brief_english Is NOT Null, 1, 0)) AS total
FROM synopsis
UNION ALL
SELECT
'briefbng' as status,
Sum(If(brief_bangla Is Null, 1, 0)) AS total
FROM synopsis
```

[Difference between Union All and Union](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925/what-is-the-difference-between-union-and-union-all)

Comment: @ahmad You may take a look at this (how to use union in symfony) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7981549/sql-query-with-union-in-doctrine-symfony

Comment: i know that, but the problem is i dont want to create dependency with pdo rather want to stay with orm

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tablename WHERE a IS NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT count(*) FROM tablename WHERE a IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
select sum(case a when null then 1 else 0) "Null values",
       sum(case a when null then 0 else 1) "Non-null values"
from tablename;
```

or

```
select sum(case when a is null then 1 else 0 end) count_nulls
     , count(a) count_not_nulls 
  from tablename;
```

Comment: none of them works i tried same things before and cant use union as symfony2 and doctrine querybuilder doesnt support union

Answer (score 0):

It's a by hook or by crook sort of approach but if you create a secondary table containing the titles with this schema

```
CREATE TABLE `titles` (
  `title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`title`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

and this data

```
insert into `titles`(`title`) values ( 'briefeng'), ( 'briefengnotnull'), ( 'briefbng');
```

use this query

```
SELECT t.title, IF(a.total IS NOT NULL, a.total, IF(b.total IS NOT NULL, b.total, c.total)) AS total FROM
titles t 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'briefeng' AS title, SUM(IF(brief_english IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS total FROM synopsis) a ON a.title=t.title
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'briefengnotnull' AS title, SUM(IF(brief_english IS NULL, 0, 1)) AS total FROM synopsis) b ON b.title=t.title
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 'briefbng' AS title, SUM(IF(brief_bangla  IS NULL, 1, 0)) AS total FROM synopsis) c ON c.title=t.title
```

to get this result (depending on the records in synopsis table)

```
+-----------------+-------+
| title           | total |
+-----------------+-------+
| briefbng        |     3 |
| briefeng        |     1 |
| briefengnotnull |     4 |
+-----------------+-------+
```